# Why does this Java code compile?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

In method or class scope, the line below compiles (with warning):

```
int x = x = 1;
```

In class scope, **where variables get their default values**, the following gives 'undefined reference' error:

```
int x = x + 1;
```

Isn't it the first `x = x = 1` should end up with same 'undefined reference' error? Or maybe the second line `int x = x + 1` should compile? Or there is something I am missing?

Comment: If you add the keyword `static` in the class-scope variable, as in `static int x = x + 1;`, will you get the same error? Because in C# it makes a difference if it's static or non-static.

Comment: `static int x = x + 1` fails in Java.

Comment: in c# both `int a = this.a + 1;` and `int b = 1; int a = b + 1;` in class scope  (both of which are ok in Java) fail, probably due to §17.4.5.2 - "A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created." I don't know if it's explicitly allowed somewhere but static has no such restriction. In Java the rules are different and `static int x = x + 1` fails for the same reason that `int x = x + 1` does

Comment: That anwser with a bytecode clears any doubts.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

### tl;dr

For *fields*, `int b = b + 1` is illegal because `b` is an illegal forward reference to `b`. You can actually fix this by writing `int b = this.b + 1`, which compiles without complaints.

For *local variables*, `int d = d + 1` is illegal because `d` is not initialized before use. This is **not** the case for fields, which are always default-initialized.

You can see the difference by attempting to compile

`int x = (x = 1) + x;`

as a field declaration and as a local variable declaration. The former will fail, but the latter will succeed, because of the difference in semantics.

### Introduction

First off, the rules for field and local variable initializers are very different. So this answer will tackle the rules in two parts.

We'll use this test program throughout:

```
public class test {
    int a = a = 1;
    int b = b + 1;
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        int c = c = 1;
        int d = d + 1;
    }
}
```

The declaration of `b` is invalid and fails with an `illegal forward reference` error.
The declaration of `d` is invalid and fails with an `variable d might not have been initialized` error.

The fact that these errors are different should hint that the reasons for the errors are also different.

### Fields

Field initializers in Java are governed by [JLS §8.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2), Initialization of Fields.

The *scope* of a field is defined in [JLS §6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3), Scope of a Declaration.

Relevant rules are:

- The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a class type C (§8.1.6) is the entire body of C, including any nested type declarations.
- Initialization expressions for instance variables may use the simple name of any static variable declared in or inherited by the class, even one whose declaration occurs textually later.
- Use of instance variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these instance variables are in scope. See §8.3.2.3 for the precise rules governing forward reference to instance variables.

§8.3.2.3 says:

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is
>   used only if the member is an instance (respectively static) field of
>   a class or interface C and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively static) variable initializer of C or in an instance (respectively static) initializer of C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.

You can actually refer to fields before they have been declared, except in certain cases. These restrictions are intended to prevent code like

```
int j = i;
int i = j;
```

from compiling. The Java spec says "the restrictions above are designed to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations."

What do these rules actually boil down to?

In short, the rules basically say that you *must* declare a field in advance of a reference to that field if (a) the reference is in an initializer, (b) the reference is not being assigned to, (c) the reference is a *simple name* (no qualifiers like `this.`) and (d) it is not being accessed from within an inner class. So, a forward reference that satisfies all four conditions is illegal, but a forward reference that fails on at least one condition is OK.

`int a = a = 1;` compiles because it violates (b): the reference `a` *is* being assigned to, so it's legal to refer to `a` in advance of `a`'s complete declaration.

`int b = this.b + 1` also compiles because it violates (c): the reference `this.b` is not a simple name (it's qualified with `this.`). This odd construct is still perfectly well-defined, because `this.b` has the value zero.

So, basically, the restrictions on field references within initializers prevent `int a = a + 1` from being successfully compiled.

Observe that the field declaration `int b = (b = 1) + b` will *fail* to compile, because the final `b` is still an illegal forward reference.

### Local variables

Local variable declarations are governed by [JLS §14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4), Local Variable Declaration Statements.

The *scope* of a local variable is defined in [JLS §6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3), Scope of a Declaration:

- The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

Note that initializers are within the scope of the variable being declared. So why doesn't `int d = d + 1;` compile?

The reason is due to Java's rule on **definite assignment** ([JLS §16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html)). Definite assignment basically says that every access to a local variable must have a preceding assignment to that variable, and the Java compiler checks loops and branches to ensure that assignment *always* occurs prior to any use (this is why definite assignment has an entire specification section dedicated to it). The basic rule is:

- For every access of a local variable or blank final field `x`, `x` must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.

In `int d = d + 1;`, the access to `d` is resolved to the local variable fine, but since `d` has not been assigned before `d` is accessed, the compiler issues an error. In `int c = c = 1`, `c = 1` happens first, which assigns `c`, and then `c` is initialized to the result of that assignment (which is 1).

Note that because of definite assignment rules, the local variable declaration `int d = (d = 1) + d;` *will* compile successfully (*unlike* the field declaration `int b = (b = 1) + b`), because `d` is definitely assigned by the time the final `d` is reached.

Comment: +1 for the references, however I think you got this wording wrong: "int a = a = 1; compiles because it violates (b)", if it violated any one of the 4 requirements it wouldn't compile. However it doesn't since it **IS** on the left hand side of an assignment (double negative in wording of JLS doesn't help much here). In `int b = b + 1` b is on the right (not on left) of the assignment so it would violate this...

Comment: ... What I'm not too sure of is the following: those 4 conditions must be met if the declaration does not appear textually before the assignment, in this case I think the declaration does appear "textually" before the assignment `int x = x = 1`, in which case none of this would apply.

Comment: @msam: It's a tad confusing, but basically you have to violate one of the four conditions in order to make a forward reference. If your forward reference *satisfies* all four conditions, it is illegal.

Comment: @msam: Also, the full declaration only goes into effect after the initializer.

Comment: @mrfishie: Big answer, but there's a surprising amount of depth in the Java spec. The question is not so simple as it seems on the surface. (I wrote a subset-of-Java compiler once upon a time, so I am quite familiar with many of the ins and outs of the JLS).

Comment: "Contrary to some other answers, this will never produce a Java warning, because it is equivalent to c = (c = 1)"...except that it **does** produce a warning (in eclipse)

Answer (score 86):

```
int x = x = 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = 1;
x = x; //warning here
```

while in

```
int x = x + 1;
```

first we need to compute `x+1` but the value of x is not known so you get an error (the compiler knows that the value of x is not known)

Comment: This plus the hint on the right-associativity from OpenSauce I found very useful.

Comment: I thought the return value of an assignment was the value being assigned, not the variable value.

Comment: @zzzzBov is correct. `int x = x = 1;` is equivalent to `int x = (x = 1)`, **not** `x = 1; x = x;`. You should not get a compiler warning for doing this.

Comment: `int x = x = 1;` s equivalent to int `x = (x = 1)` because of  right-associativity  of `=` operator

Comment: @nneonneo and `int x = (x = 1)` is equivalent to `int x; x = 1; x = x;` (variable declaration, evaluation of field initializer, assignment of variable to result of said evaluation), hence the warning

Comment: Did you get a warning? Because I did not. I'd like to know exactly what code and what compiler you used to get a warning.

Comment: @nneonneo yes "The assignment to variable x has no effect" that was the whole point of the op's question

Comment: http://ideone.com/xHCBTi no warning. Can you provide a code sample that does give a warning?

Comment: @nneonneo The exact same code in eclipse gives a warning (can be switched off from preferences), In terms of bytecode  `ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 0
    ICONST_1
    DUP_X1
    PUTFIELD Main.a : I
    PUTFIELD Main.a : I`
    Note the double assignment (first for x = 1, then for x = (evaluation of x=1, which is 1)

Comment: Actually, I think that does `a = 1; a = 1;`.

Comment: @nneonneo maybe it is equivalent to `int x = (x = 1)`, but the compiler first creates the variable `x`, so it exists before assigning a value. Then it assigns 1 to `x`, and then sets `x` to that value.

Comment: @nneonneo yes the bytecode does a=1 twice, but there is no way to do `a=a` directly. Note that `int a = b = a = 1` does not produce the same warning, even though it assigns a to 1 twice.

Comment: @msam: The compiler is free to do anything it wants provided it produces code that has the same effect as the prescribed JLS behaviour. Eclipse is also free to issue any warnings it wants above and beyond the diagnostics prescribed by Java; it will issue warnings for stylistic and semantic issues that are out of the scope of the JLS. (In any case I've removed the offending sentence in my answer because it was confusing).

Answer (score 41):

It's roughly equivalent to:

```
int x;
x = 1;
x = 1;
```

Firstly, `int <var> = <expression>;` is always equivalent to

```
int <var>;
<var> = <expression>;
```

In this case, your expression is `x = 1`, which is also a statement. `x = 1` is a valid statement, since the var `x` has already been declared. It is also an expression with the value 1, which is then assigned to `x` again.

Comment: Ok, but if it went like you say, why in class scope the second statement gives an error? I mean you get default `0` value for ints, so I would expect the result to be 1, not the `undefined reference`.

Comment: Take a look at @izogfif answer. Seems like working, because C++ compiler assigns default values to variables. The same way java does for class-level variables.

Comment: @Marcin: in Java, ints are *not* initialized to 0 when they're local variables. They are only initialized to 0 if they are member variables. So in your second line, `x + 1` has no defined value, because `x` is uninitialized.

Comment: @OpenSauce But `x` **is** defined as a member variable ("in class scope").

Comment: @JacobRaihle: Ah ok, didn't spot that part. I'm not sure the bytecode to initialize a var to 0 will be generated by the compiler if it sees there is an explicit initialization instruction. There's an article here that goes into some detail about class and object initialization, although I don't think it addresses this exact issue: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-2001/jw-1102-java101.html

Comment: take a look at [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), specifically Example 12.5-2. Dynamic Dispatch During Instance Creation - it's value has to be initialized to 0 even if there is an explicit initialisation

Comment: @OpenSauce: In this particular case, the answer has nothing to do with right associativity. The grammar is defined simply as `type variable = expression` (with additions for multiple variables and `[]`), so the only way that `int x = x = 1` can be parsed is as `int x = (x = 1)`. This would be true even if `=` were left-associative.

Comment: That's so nice to correct your answer after some one posted a right one. ;)

Answer (score 12):

In java or in any modern language, assignment comes from the right.

Suppose if you are having two variables x and y,

```
int z = x = y = 5;
```

This statement is valid and this is how the compiler splits them.

```
y = 5;
x = y;
z = x; // which will be 5
```

But in your case

```
int x = x + 1;
```

The compiler gave an exception because, it splits like this.

```
x = 1; // oops, it isn't declared because assignment comes from the right.
```

Answer (score 8):

`int x = x = 1;` is not equal to:

```
int x;
x = 1;
x = x;
```

javap helps us again, these are JVM instruction generated for this code:

```
0: iconst_1    //load constant to stack
1: dup         //duplicate it
2: istore_1    //set x to constant
3: istore_1    //set x to constant
```

more like:

```
int x = 1;
x = 1;
```

Here is no reason to throw undefined reference error. There is now usage of variable prior to it's initialization, so this code fully comply with specification. **In fact there is no usage of variable at all**, just assignments. And JIT compiler will go even further, it will eliminate such constructions. Saying honestly, I don't understand how this code is connected to JLS's specification of variable initialization and usage. No usage no problems. ;)

Please correct if I'am wrong. I cant figure out why other answers, which refer to many JLS paragraphs collect so many pluses. These paragraphs has nothing in common with this case. Just two serial assignments and no more.

If we write:

```
int b, c, d, e, f;
int a = b = c = d = e = f = 5;
```

is equal to:

```
f = 5
e = 5
d = 5
c = 5
b = 5
a = 5
```

Right most expression is just assigned to variables one by one, without any recursion. We can mess variables any way we like :

```
a = b = c = f = e = d = a = a = a = a = a = e = f = 5;
```

Answer (score 7):

In `int x = x + 1;` you add 1 to x , so what is the value of `x`, it's not created yet.

But in `int x=x=1;` will compile with no error because you assign 1 to `x`.

Answer (score 5):

Your first piece of code contains a second `=` instead of a plus. This will compile anywhere while the second piece of code will not compile in either place.

Answer (score 5):

In the second piece of code, x is used before its declaration, while in the the first piece of code it is just assigned twice which doesn't make sense but is valid.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break it down step by step, right associative

```
int x = x = 1
```

`x = 1`, assign 1 to a variable x

`int x = x`, assign what x is to itself, as an int. Since x was previously assigned as 1, it retains 1, albeit in a redundant fashion.

That compiles fine.

```
int x = x + 1
```

`x + 1`, add one to a variable x. However, x being undefined this will cause a compile error.

`int x = x + 1`, thus this line compile errors as the right portion of the equals will not compile adding one to an unassigned variable

Comment: No, it's right-associative when there are two `=` operators, so it's the same as `int x = (x = 1);`.

Comment: Ah, my orders off. Sorry about that. Should have done them backwards. I've switched it around now.

Answer (score 3):

The second one `int x=x=1` is compile because you are assigning the value to the x but in other case `int x=x+1` here the variable x is not initialized , Remember in java local variable are not initialized to default value.
Note If it's (`int x=x+1`) in class scope also then also it will give compilation error as the variable is not created.

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = x + 1;
```

compiles successfully in Visual Studio 2008 with warning

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used`
```

Comment: Interresting. Is it C/C++?

Comment: @Marcin: yes, it is C++.
@msam: sorry, I think I saw tag `c` instead of `java` but apparently it was the other question.

Comment: It compiles because in C++, compilers assign default values for primitive types. Use `bool y;` and `y==true` will return false.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati, is it some kind of a standard in C++ compiler? Because when I compile `void main() { int x = x + 1; printf("%d ", x); }` in Visual Studio 2008, in Debug I get the exception `Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'x' is being used without being initialized.` and in Release I get number `1896199921` printed in the console.

Comment: Doesn't know well but it also works in `MingW` and `TurboC++`.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Talking about other languages: In C#, for a `static` field (class-level static variable), the same rules apply. For example a field declared as `public static int x = x + 1;` compiles without warning in Visual C#. Possibly the same in Java?

Answer (score 2):

x is not initialised in `x = x + 1`;.

**The Java programming language is statically-typed, which means that all variables must first be declared before they can be used.**

See [primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: The need to initialise variables before using their values has nothing to do with static typing.  Statically typed: you need to declare what type a variable is.  Initialise-before-use: it needs to provably have a value before you can use the value.

Comment: @JonBright: The need to declare types of variables also has nothing to do with static typing. For example, there are statically typed languages with type inference.

Comment: @hammar, the way I see it, you can argue it two ways: with type inference, you're implicitly declaring the variable's type in a way that the system can infer.  Or, type inference is a third way, where variables aren't dynamically typed at runtime, but are at source level, depending on their use and the inferences thus made.  Either way, the statement remains true.  But you're right, I wasn't thinking about other type systems.

Answer (score 2):

The line of code does not compile with a warning because of how the code actually works.
When you run the code `int x = x = 1`, Java first creates the variable `x`, as defined. **Then** it runs the assignment code (`x = 1`). Since `x` is already defined, the system has no errors setting `x` to 1. This returns the value 1, because that is now the value of `x`. Therefor, `x` is now finally set as 1.
Java basically executes the code as if it was this:

```
int x;
x = (x = 1); // (x = 1) returns 1 so there is no error
```

However, in your second piece of code, `int x = x + 1`, the `+ 1` statement requires `x` to be defined, which by then it is not. Since assignment statements always mean the code to the right of the `=` is run first, the code will fail because `x` is undefined. Java would run the code like this:

```
int x;
x = x + 1; // this line causes the error because `x` is undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

Complier read statements from right to left and we designed to do the opposite. That's why it annoyed at first. Make this a habbit to read statements (code) from right to left you won't have such problem.